# Assign default widgets to all sites in a multisite network

Tags: multisite, widgets

I created a widget for sidebar and footer in wordpress multiuser site. I want to make the widgets assigned in MAIN WIDGET AREA and SECONDARY WIDGET AREA by default when new site's created.

Is there anyway to do it ?

I am using wordpress 3.7.1

I tried [this](http://mu.wordpress.org/forums/topic/16788#post-94586) method, but didn't works, is it syntax problem calling that function ?

Comment: Can you also let us know, what have you tried till now?

Comment: I created the widget and now manually assign to each sites!!!

Comment: I meant what have you tried to assign the widgets on new site's creation. What have you researched on this ? What have you found over web?

Comment: I can do it by hardcode to sidebar.php, but I trying the better way, because users need to change the images them self.

Comment: **`wpmu_new_blog`** is the hook you can build your function on. You will have to find a way to do this. Sharing a blog which does something else using the same hook when a sub site is created http://drujoopress.wordpress.com/2013/11/12/wordpress-multisite-wpmu-new-blog-hook/

Comment: @MarutiMohanty Its working, please type as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`wpmu_new_blog`** is the hook you can build your function on.

You will have to find a way to do this.

Sharing a blog which does something else using the same hook when a sub site is created.

[`Link to the blog`](http://drujoopress.wordpress.com/2013/11/12/wordpress-multisite-wpmu-new-blog-hook/)